# One liner for either dynamically creating key in associative array or, if it exists, pushing value to existing key's array

Tags: javascript

Taking this data structure:

```
  data = [
    {
      group: '4',
      data: [
        {
          type: 'Type 1',
          value: 1
        },
        {
          type: 'Type 2',
          value: 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      group: '5',
      data: [
        {
          type: 'Type 1',
          value: 3
        },
        {
          type: 'Type 2',
          value: 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I would like to create an associative array that looks like:

```
{
  'Type 1': [1, 3],
  'Type 2': [2, 5]
}
```

My current solution:

```
const arr = data.reduce((acc, p) => {
  const updatedAcc = acc;

  p.data.forEach(d => {
    if (updatedAcc[d.type] === undefined) {
      updatedAcc[d.type] = [d.value];
    } else {
      updatedAcc[d.type].push(d.value);
    }
  });

  return updatedAcc;
}, {});
```

How can this be done in one line or with an implicit return, keeping the ability to handle an arbitrary amount of different "types" (meaning different strings for the data.type property)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly modified version of @Olian04 to simplify the second reduce.

```js
const data = [{
    group: '4',
    data: [{
        type: 'Type 1',
        value: 1
      }, {
        type: 'Type 2',
        value: 2
      }
    ]
  }, {
    group: '5',
    data: [{
        type: 'Type 1',
        value: 3
      }, {
        type: 'Type 2',
        value: 5
      }
    ]
  }
];

const out = data
  .reduce((res, v) => ([...res, ...v.data]), []) // Flatten data
  .reduce((res, v) => (res[v.type] = res[v.type] || []).push(v.value)&&res, {});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first flatten the data into a single array (the first reduce), and then construct the new data format from that (the second reduce).

```js
const data = [{
    group: '4',
    data: [{
        type: 'Type 1',
        value: 1
      }, {
        type: 'Type 2',
        value: 2
      }
    ]
  }, {
    group: '5',
    data: [{
        type: 'Type 1',
        value: 3
      }, {
        type: 'Type 2',
        value: 5
      }
    ]
  }
];

const out = data
  .reduce((res, v) => ([...res, ...v.data]), []) // Flatten data
  .reduce((res, v) => { // Convert to new format
    if (v.type in res) {
      res[v.type].push(v.value);
    } else {
      res[v.type] = [v.value];
    }
    return res;
  }, {});

console.log(out);
```

I should add that this does not remove duplicate "values" so you will have to add that logic on your own if it is desired.

Less readable but more compact version:

```js
const data = [{
    group: '4',
    data: [{
        type: 'Type 1',
        value: 1
      }, {
        type: 'Type 2',
        value: 2
      }
    ]
  }, {
    group: '5',
    data: [{
        type: 'Type 1',
        value: 3
      }, {
        type: 'Type 2',
        value: 5
      }
    ]
  }
];

const out = data
  .reduce((res, v) => ([...res, ...v.data]), [])
  .reduce((res, v) => 
    v.type in res ? {...res, [v.type]: [...res[v.type], v.value]} : {...res, [v.type]: [v.value]}, 
  {});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Flattening it out first makes sense, but I was hoping for an implicit return in the second reduce

Comment: @EricEttensohn I don't see why, that would only serve to make it harder to read... but you could use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Maybe -> `.reduce((res, v) => (res[v.type] = res[v.type] ||
    []).push(v.value)&&res, {})`  @EricEttensohn try that for the implicit return on second reduce.

Comment: @Olian04 you'd still be using a temporary variable, I'm looking for an implicit return, without using a temporary variable. As for why, think of it as code golf. Why not?

Comment: @EricEttensohn that is an implicit return, where do you find the "temporary" variable?

Comment: @Keith that worked! Olian04 if you want to edit your answer to include Keith's suggestion, or Keith if you want to create a new answer with your code I'll accept it.

Comment: @EricEttensohn would you mind explaining what part of `v.type in res ? {...res, [v.type]: [...res[v.type], v.value]} : {...res, [v.type]: [v.value]}` is storing a temporary value?

Comment: @Olian04 that solution doesn't work, values are overwritten.

Comment: @EricEttensohn Could you provide some example data where you are experiencing this behavior?

Comment: Olian04, the temporary variable comment I made referred to the solution you said was "less readable," which used an explicit return. I'm sorry, it didn't have a temporary variable but with an explicit return it did not satisfy the requirements of the question.

Comment: @EricEttensohn I've only edited the post once (check the history) and that's when i added the snippet with the ternary. Its always looked like it does now. If there once was a problem with it, than that problem remains. So could you provide the data set were you are experiencing this problem?

Comment: @Olian04 the data provided in the original post results in `{
  "Type 1": [
    3
  ],
  "Type 2": [
    5
  ]
}`

Comment: @EricEttensohn Sorry, but no it doesn't. It results in `{"Type 1": [1,3],"Type 2": [2,5]}`. You can run the code your self by pressing "Run code snippet"

Comment: @Olian04 apologies, I was running it locally and failed to copy it over correctly. It works. I accepted keith's answer because his post satisfied the requirements of the question. you have an answer that doesn't satisfy the requirements (explicit return) posted above one that does, so it's not as clear. I understand that you were going for the most readable answer, but I was looking for brevity over readability. Thanks for working through this with me.

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to do the assignment in a single line, you could use a ternary operator

```
const arr = data.reduce((acc,p)=>{
    const updatedAcc = acc;

    p.data.forEach(d=>{
        updatedAcc[d.type] = (d.type in updatedAcc) ? updatedAcc[d.type].concat([d.value]) : [d.value];
    });
    return updatedAcc;
}
, {});
```

Comment: This one uses an explicit return, I'm looking for an implicit return from the reduce function